# SOAP curl error sending data to web service: "Server was unable to process request."

Tags: php, html, xml, curl, soap

I'm setting up a script that sends data to a web service through PHP curl, but I'm having the following error:

```
soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s
```

I can't find documentation relating to this issue on PHP curl, the issue is highly unspecific too.

I'm using the example request provided by the web service itself verbatim. Tried sending a custom request with random valid data, but that didn't help.

Also, requests to other, simpler web services using the same code seem to work just fine, which means the code logic *should* be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with me now needing to use CDATA brackets enclosing the XML code in order for it to work properly.